# Delete or edit my poor novice question?

Tags: discussion

I have asked a question:

[How to compare key value in one array with key value in another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753311/how-to-compare-key-value-in-one-array-with-key-value-in-another-array)

I have realised that due to my confusion I asked a poor question which didn't answer the question I was trying to ask. This is largely as I am a novice.

I can frame it much better and ask a smaller, focused question.

Should I:
Edit to add my new question underneath the original and explain why it was not asking what I wanted?
Delete the question and ask again?

Thanks

Comment: Since it has answers already, the general rule is do not edit for your new question if it would invalidate the previous answers.

Comment: Also, you cannot delete that question. You may only self-delete a question if (a) it has no answers or (b) it has only one answer that has no upvotes. You have two answers on that question, one of which has an upvote to boot. Also, huge tip: Format your code as code. When typing your question, you can highlight your code blocks and press the `{}` button, and for inline code, you can put backticks(`) around it.